# Touchscreen Setting 14.04

Tags: 14.04, multi-touch, touchscreen

So I installed 14.04 on an Asus Q200E with touch screen. Previously I had 12.04 and did a new clean install.  I was looking forward to better touch screen support. Touchscreen works better, no multitouch support, and I can't find any settings for it.  Also when the computer suspends and resumes touchscreen doesn't work unless I logout/ login.  Where can I find settings for touchscreen?  and is there a command line way to reboot the touchscreen when it stops working?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not terribly sure about multitouch, but tablet and touchscreen can be config'd under Settings > Mouse and Touchpad, and then by selecting your touch device from the drop down menu. In mine, I can select "Serial Wacom Tablet touch" and then select the "Tablet" tab below, which allows me to configure the tracking and rotation.